# Are minority majority districts Republican gerrymanders in disguise?

Tags: united-states, voting-districts, gerrymandering

In the USA, white voters have a tendency to vote Republican (depending on where you live, in places like California and Vermont that is not the case) and nonwhite  voters as a whole vote Democratic almost everywhere.

There are laws requiring lawmakers to make minority majority districts. I believe this law creates the unintended consequence because of the fact I stated above that this creates Republican gerrymanders by packing nonwhite (and thus mostly Democratic) voters into separate districts.

What I am asking is: Do Republicans have more seats because of minority majority districts packing in Democrats together? To be clear. I picked on Republicans because: 1. Majority minority districts usually have lower than average concentrations of Republicans relative to their state; 2. This type of district has been ordered as a form of affirmative action. (See *Bush vs. Vera. Note the justices that voted NO/unconstitutional on this case.)

Comment: An interesting counterexample: Lea County New Mexico. That is why I said ALMOST everywhere. Most to all large enough nonwhite Republican areas are Hispanic or at least mostly non-black, owing in part to their geographic diversity.

Comment: It's a [complicated issue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerrymandering_in_the_United_States#Affirmative) and the way you've asked this seems to solicit more opinion than fact(s).

Comment: Do you mean "majority minority"?

Comment: No. I used minority majority to be nicer. And, please note that I am asking it in an objective way

Comment: And the same principle can apply to Democrats. So why only Republicans?

Comment: @Machavity I assume the focus is on Republicans since it’s generally assumed that having majority minority districts is better for Democrats (as opposed to the pre-Civil Rights era practice to totally gerrymandering away non-white political power) but I think it’s too speculative as is since the answer depends on what they’re relaxed with

Comment: And why your new q is hard to answer: because optimal gerrymandering strategies are quite complicated: https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/aer.98.1.113

Comment: That is why the focus is on Republicans. It is also that there were laws put in that *could be seen* that way. Nonwhites lean Democratic more than whites lean Republican, and that is even true in most of the South. **This question is asked in good faith.**

Comment: According to https://www.econstor.eu/bitstream/10419/197758/1/1010162896.pdf (pp. 35-36) the answer seems to yes, but such complex statistical models have been [(famously) rejected](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibberish#Gobbledygook) by SCOTUS.

Comment: What I am saying is that it is NOT intended to be an attack on Republicans. I could theoretically ask "would packing non college white voters in Virginia be a Democratic gerrymander?". But this is a more contentious issue that has been raised by others including the paper raised by Fizz.

Comment: Doesn’t the answer to this depend on what they’re replaced with? I’m pretty sure that every map in question could be redesigned to have either more or less Republican seats, depending on how the minority voters were distributed among the new districts